# Limit the maximum size of video download

Tags: html, asp-classic, web-config

I'm downloading a video online and I want to limit the size allowed. I tried to add this to **web.config**

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout ="3600" maxRequestLength ="2000" appRequestQueueLimit ="100" requestValidationMode ="2.0" requestLengthDiskThreshold ="2000000" />
```

But it does not work.

Here is my ASP code :

```
'Creation du Guid
Set TypeLib = Server.CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
guid1 = TypeLib.Guid
guid1 = Left(guid1, Len(guid1)-2)
guid1 = replace(guid1, "{", "")
guid1 = replace(guid1, "}", "")
Set TypeLib = Nothing

'autoriser les mp4

set mySmartUpload = Server.CreateObject("aspSmartUpload.SmartUpload")
mySmartUpload.AllowedFilesList = "mp4"
mySmartUpload.DeniedFilesList = "bat,exe,com,asp,php,pdf,txt,doc,xls,jsp,aspx"
mySmartUpload.Upload
'chem="imagesCrop/"

ext1 = mySmartUpload.Files.Item(1).FileExt
video1 = cstr(guid1) & "." & ext1
set fichier1 = mySmartUpload.Files.Item(1)
fichier1.SaveAs(server.MapPath(chem) & "\" & video1)

set mySmartUpload = nothing
```

and my HTML input :

```
<input class="champ"  type="file" name="f1" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got 2 solutions.

In Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

This will limit file upload size to 100 MB

In SmartUpoad itself:

```
mySmartUpload.MaxFileSize = 104857600
```

That's 100 MB too.